# MYSQL SELECT - Can't select matching strings from joined tables

Tags: mysql, select, workbench

I have a list of email addresses for registrants at an upcoming trade show. I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dolp21 (email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL);
```

My contacts table contains a column: email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

I am trying to see which of these registrants is an existing client. Here is my query in workbench that returns 0 results and no errors even though I can immediately see several email addresses that I recognize as being existing clients:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.firstName,' ',c.lastName) AS 'Contact'
FROM contacts c
JOIN dolp21 d ON TRIM(lcase(d.email))=TRIM(lcase(c.email))
ORDER BY c.lastName, c.firstName
;
```

Any idea why I'm not getting any matches?

Comment: Why do you need in TRIM()? does the value may contain leading spaces? Why do you need in LCASE()? Does the columns have case-sensitive collations? *Any idea why I'm not getting any matches?* Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables (taken with SHOW CREATE TABLE) and INSERT INTO (3-5 rows per table) with the values which must match but are not selected.

Comment: The registration spreadsheet with the email addresses was created by a third party and I can't be sure that there isn't white space present. The spreadsheet does contain a good amount of capitalization which we don't use when inputting email addresses. The create table statement for contacts is fairly long as there are 36 columns and as for the INSERT INTO statements, I uploaded the email addresses into dolp21 via LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: *The create table statement for contacts is fairly long* The columns unrelated to the question (and constraints/indices) may be easily skipped, only `email` columns definitions and tables options needed (and maybe first/last name from contacts), the same for sample data. *I uploaded the email addresses into dolp21 via LOAD DATA INFILE* You must trim all values and normalize them to lower case during the import.

Comment: Does the encoding of the CSV upload file matter (eg. UTF-8, etc)?

Comment: CREATE TABLE contacts (email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

Comment: *Does the encoding of the CSV upload file matter (eg. UTF-8, etc)?* Of course, character set must be specified in LOAD DATA. *CREATE TABLE contacts (email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);* Please show the citate extracted from SHOW CREATE TABLE output - DEFAULT CHARSET and COLLATE options must be specified for a column and/or for a table. For both tables.

Answer (score 0):

When I exported the dolp21 table to CSV file and then opened the CSV file in Notepad++, I discovered that each email address was followed by two carriage returns inside the quotes and then of course a line feed at the end of each row like so:

"name@company.comCRCR"LF
"person@business.comCRCR"LF

I ran an update query to clean that up and now my select query works!